# Finding the last row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I have a script that is copying data from a sheet on a google sheet to a different google sheet.  It's supposed to find the last row and then copy the data 1 row below that.  It has been working but for some reason it started overwriting data. Just a note, I'm not a script writer.  I used chatGPT to write the script. The last row with data is 5457 but it wants to start on 5441, not sure why.  Below is the script.  Attached is the picture before and after of the target data.  The before has a blank space on row 5450. I will be grateful for any help or ideas.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODFKM.png
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ljjpn.png)

```
function copyNewData() {
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Q7outb60oBc84hJB_ZdQf8He6eU1kFeMjz8tyQBi0XY").getSheetByName("CurrentStock");
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1hJivcxWR43b2cyEJP5Nu8xh-In7upH79zlhbL2ZhatE").getSheetByName("CurrentStock");
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 1, sourceSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 7).getValues();
  var lastRow = targetSheet.getRange("A:A").getValues().filter(String).length + 1;
  var destinationRange = targetSheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, sourceData.length, sourceData[0].length); // Adjust the number of columns
  destinationRange.setValues(sourceData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit 12/14/23
I found a consistent way to get the last row of data.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var lastRow = dataRange.length;

Logger.log(lastRow);
```

My lastRow var I will do `dataRange.length + 1` if I need the first empty row, in your case you might do `dataRange.length - 1` if you are needing the second to last row, then doing something like

```
var copiedData = lastRow.getValues();
```

Then do what you need with the copiedData var.

////////////////////////////////

I'm not sure if I have a solution for you, but .getLastRow() does not seem to work how you would expect it to work. There are a lot of GAS videos on YouTube that are ~2 years old and older that use .getLastRow() and it will find the last row with data in your selected range, but it does not seem to do that as of the last year or so.

One example of this is [this video](https://youtu.be/R8mZSOKeUk4?list=PLpi0Hux2ipAF1_yPg7n4qaCba9XEzYbBo) where the guy uses `varName.getLastRow() + 1` to write the data to the row below the last row of data. I cannot replicate this behavior even copying his spreadsheet and his code line for line. The section I'm talking about starts at 3:50 in the video.

Any time I've tried to use .getLastRow() it always returns the last row of the entire spreadsheet even if I specify a range var and do something like

```
var rangeA = mySheet.getRange("A1:B50");
rangeA.getLastRow();
```

It would still try to return row 1000, or whatever the last row number is.

Based on my experience it seems you would need to modify your code to loop through your sourceData.length variable to find the index of the last row, then do something like `lastRowIndex - 1` then get the value(s).

If I am completely wrong here I would love to know from those of you with more knowledge and experience because it has been a thorn in my side for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function copyNewData() {
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Q7outb60oBc84hJB_ZdQf8He6eU1kFeMjz8tyQBi0XY").getSheetByName("CurrentStock");
  const tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1hJivcxWR43b2cyEJP5Nu8xh-In7upH79zlhbL2ZhatE");
  var targetSheet = tss.getSheetByName("CurrentStock");
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 1, sourceSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 7).getValues();
  var lastRow = getColumnHeight1(1,targetSheet,tss);
  var destinationRange = targetSheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, sourceData.length, sourceData[0].length); // Adjust the number of columns
  destinationRange.setValues(sourceData);
}

function getColumnHeight1(col, sh, ss) {
  var ss = ss || SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = sh || ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col = col || sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var rcA = [];
  if (sh.getLastRow()) { rcA = sh.getRange(1, col, sh.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat().reverse(); }
  let s = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < rcA.length; i++) {
    if (rcA[i].toString().length == 0) {
      s++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return rcA.length - s;
}
```

Comment: This did not work. It moved a few rows down the but still did not copy data after the last row.

Comment: I would need to see your spreadsheet to help you